# How do I replace a variable name with a value in a Python AST?

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I want my users to be able to enter arithmetical expressions on the command line in Python syntax and have the variable names replaced by values at runtime. I don't want to just use `eval`, I want to use [Abstract Syntax Trees](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html).

For example, say I want to rewrite every variable in an AST with the value `3.5` and then evaluate it. From reading the documentation, I came up with this.

```
import ast

class RewriteName(ast.NodeTransformer):

    def visit_Name(self, node):
        return ast.copy_location(ast.Num(n=3.5, ctx=node.ctx), node)

tree = ast.parse('a + b', 'eval')
tree = RewriteName().visit(tree)
ast.fix_missing_locations(tree)
o = compile(tree, '<string>', 'eval')
print(eval(o))
```

I want this to print `7.0` but instead I get the following error.

```
o = compile(tree, '<string>', 'eval')
TypeError: expected Expression node, got Module
```

I understand that AST confusing nomenclature about `Expression` vs. `Expr`, but I haven't been able to find an example of how to sort through this. I tried various arguments to `compile` including running it on various subnodes of `tree` thinking that one of those might be Expression I need, but so far without success.

What is example code that makes this work?

Comment: You're calling `ast.parse()` wrong - the mode (which must be 'eval' if you're going to compile the modified AST in 'eval' mode) is the 3rd parameter, not the second.

Comment: Yep. If I change the line to `tree = ast.parse('a + b', '', 'eval')` it works. You should add this as an answer so that I can mark the question resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was calling `ast.parse` with the wrong arguments. The correct call is

```
tree = ast.parse('a+b', '', eval)
```

(See the comment above.)